# Python M2Crypto.SSL.Checker.NoCertificate Exception

Tags: python, exception, m2crypto

I reached out to comp.lang.python to see if anyone had any ideas about this issue.  I've received no response on the mailing list so I decided to reach out here.

I have a weird quirk with the M2Crypto module and I hope someone would be able to point me in the right direction.  I am working with a colleague to develop an internal tool to check SSL certificates on a list of IPv4 addresses obtained via stdin.

We are using M2Crypto to help with validating the certificates.  If we only have it check one IPv4 address, it is able to provide us with the correct certificate and we are able to do our validation checks on the information that the SSL certificate contains.

However, if we try to check multiple IPv4 addresses we receive the "M2Crypto.SSL.Checker.NoCertificate".  There are some cases where we should be receiving this.  However, regardless of what the second or third IPv4 address is (even if it tested good as the first one), it will fail.

Context creation:

```
    global context 

    context = M2Crypto.SSL.Context() 
    if sys.platform.startswith('linux'): 
            context.load_verify_info(capath="/etc/ssl/certs/")
    elif sys.platform.startswith('darwin'): 
            context.load_verify_info(cafile=certfile) 
    else: 
            print "Unknown platform, bail!" 
            exit(1) 
    context.set_allow_unknown_ca(True) 
    context.set_verify(M2Crypto.SSL.verify_none,9)
```

Socket creation:

```
    conn = M2Crypto.SSL.Connection(context) 
    socket.setdefaulttimeout(2.0) 
    conn.set_socket_read_timeout(M2Crypto.SSL.timeout(sec=2)) 
    conn.set_socket_write_timeout(M2Crypto.SSL.timeout(sec=2)) 

    try: 
            conn.connect((ip,443))
    # we can the catch the exception here, but it shouldn't be failing
```

The above two portions of code exist in their own functions.  The context creation is called only once, as the context is used globally for all connections.  I initially thought this may have been the issue, and then tried having it create the context on each loop with no change.

The latter block gets called as part of the loop over the array of addresses.  The IP is passed from the caller.

-Tim

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask...are you sure it's not just validating a single certificate, but instead validating the only certificate you have installed in your cert-store "/etc/ssl/certs/"

http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#verify-new

Comment: It's pulling the certificate from a webserver hosted on another system.  It uses the '.pem' files in /etc/ssl/certs to determine which CAs are trusted and then validate against those.  There are multiple .pem files hosted in '/etc/ssl/certs' on Debian-derived distributions.

The same issue also occurs on a Mac OS X system using a single file that was generated from Mozilla's trusted CAs.

Comment: Python ssl library is built atop OpenSSL. Try manually verifying the certificates to confirm your certificate store is configured correctly. Getting /etc/ssl/certs working correctly can be a challenge. You can verify certs using "OpenSSL verify".  http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#verify-standard

Comment: The certificate store is not the issue here.  When we are checking one IP it verifies properly.  It connects, and our validation checks work.  When trying to connect to get the cert from any subsequent hosts we get a NoCertificate exception.  Would leads me to believe it is not receiving a certificate from the server as it's happening during the connect.  OpenSSL also verifies the store is valid.  Traceback: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/575594/

Answer (score 0):

So after digging around it turns out setting the timeout(s) was causing the problem.  I removed the following code and it started to work perfectly.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(2.0) 
conn.set_socket_read_timeout(M2Crypto.SSL.timeout(sec=2)) 
conn.set_socket_write_timeout(M2Crypto.SSL.timeout(sec=2))
```

-Tim